# В чем смысловая нагрузка сочетания "только успевай"?

Tags: смысл, частица

В чем смысловая нагрузка сочетания "только успевай" в следующих предложениях?

1. Рыба клевала как никогда - только успевай вытаскивать.
2. Деньги потекут рекой - только успевай карманы набивать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Только успевай*** — это гипербола, стилистическая фигура, то есть средство художественной выразительности, разновидность тропа с количественным значением.

Гипербола основана **на преувеличении** свойств, качеств, размеров предмета или явления.

В первой части предложений уже использовано **сравнение** (*как никогда, потекут рекой*), а во второй части художественный образ дополняется **количественной оценкой**, то есть  усиливается еще в большей степени.